# Unexpected behaviour of for

Tags: bash

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=','
i=0

for j in `cat database | head -n 1`; do
   variables[$i]=$j
   i=`expr $i + 1`
done

k=0

for l in `cat database | tail -n $(expr $(cat database | wc -l) - 1)`; do
   echo -n $k

   k=`expr $k + 1`

   if [ $k -eq 3 ]; then
      k=0
   fi
done
```

Input file

```
a,b,c
d,e,f
g,e,f
```

Output

```
01201
```

Expected output

```
012012
```

The question is why the for skips last echo? It is weird, because if I change $k to $l echo will run 6 times.

Comment: Tips for getting answers faster: paste code directly into the question (@Mat has already fixed this) and, if possible, adapt the code to run without prerequisites others are unlikely to have; do not include code unrelated to the problem.

Comment: You will also want to fix the [useless uses of `cat`](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html).  Meow galore!

Comment: @tripleee: Tone is hard to read in comments. I was genuinely trying to be helpful, based on the (possibly mistaken) assumption that the OP is a newbie. I based my advice on what made it hard for me to answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**:

@thom's analysis is correct. You can fix the problem by changing `IFS=','` to `IFS=$',\n'`.

My original statements below may be of general interest, but do not address the specific problem.
If accidental shell expansions were a concern, here's how the loop could be rewritten (assuming it's practical to read everything into an array variable first):

```
IFS=$',\n' read -d '' -r -a fields < <(echo $'*,b,c\nd,e,f\ng,h,i')
for field in "${fields[@]}"; do
  # $field is '*' in 1st iteration, then 'b', 'c', 'd',...
done
```

**Original statements**:

Just a few general pointers:

- You should use a `while` loop rather than `for` to read command output - see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001; the short of it: with `for`, the input lines are subject to various shell expansions.
- A missing iteration typically stems from the last input line missing a terminating `\n` (or a separator as defined in `$IFS`). With a `while` loop, you can use the following approach to address this: `while read -r line || [[ -n $line ]]; do …`

For instance, your 2nd `for` loop could be rewritten as (using process substitution as input to avoid creating a subshell with a separate variable scope):

```
while read -r l || [[ -n $l ]]; do …; done < <(cat database | tail -n $(expr $(cat database | wc -l) - 1))
```

Finally, you could benefit from using modern bashisms: for instance,

```
k=`expr $k + 1`
```

could be rewritten much more succinctly as `(( ++k ))` (which will run faster, too).

Answer (score 2):

Your code expects after EVERY read variable a comma but you only give this:

```
a,b,c
d,e,f
g,e,f
```

instead of this:

```
a,b,c,
d,e,f,
g,e,f,
```

so it reads:

```
d,e,f'\n'g,e,f
```

and that is equal to 5 values, not 6

Comment: Great analysis; a simple fix is to change `IFS=','` to `IFS=$',\n'`.